# How to associate thumbnail with its video

Tags: html, mysql, video, thumbnails

I have a video and its thumbnail. Video is upploaded to 'video' folder and its thumbnail to 'image' folder. The question is: how do I associate them, so later on I can use them correctely and some thoubnail wont get used with unapprorriate video it doent belong. The path to them will be stored in table vid. I was thinking about giving to a thumbnail the same name as the name of video, but than - if more than one video get same name - everything will be mixed up. So, any ideas?

(Sorry for the, maybe, stupid question; I just need the right drift...the right idea. So, how does Youtube knows which thumbnail belongs to which video?...)

Comment: YouTube has those eleven character IDs. It’s pretty obvious.

Comment: not to me... so, the image and the video have same IDs? How is that? Ho wdo i do that? Explain. please, the mysql table structure

Comment: For example, youtube allows video thumbnails once your account is verified. They send you a text or call with the code for you to enter. If you are saving them on your computer, then I would name them the watch? name end g5-TXR3Cmrk

Comment: i didnt get it! not even one bit. perhaps u didnt get my question correctely. I have uploaded video and jquery makes a thumbnail for it - next time i ll want to show thumbnail instead of video but if i click on play button and real video should appear - so here! : I need to know which video to choose from db based on its thumbnail...

Answer (score 0):

Im going to be using youtube as an example here

Every youtube video is assigned an 11 character number in base64 on creation, essentially a very large, random number. Associated with this number is a video, thumbnail, description, and who made the video.

I'm guessing this is all stored in a row on a table

When someone needs to view the video or link or whatever this row is selected and image with a title/path is pulled from the row and inserted into thumbnail slot

Hope this helps, Michael